# Setup AD FS 3.0 Proxy when Primary AD FS Server is behind firewall

Tags: proxy, adfs

I am trying to setup an AD FS Proxy server. In my case, my AD FS Server is behind a network firewall and is accessible only within the intranet. I have spawned a DMZ machine and have set it up as a Web Application Proxy(WAP). I want to use AD FS as the IdP using this proxy server. The AD FS Proxy can access the internal AD FS Server and am able to pull up the configuration from the internal AD FS Server. The appropriate Firewall rules are in place which allow for communication to the ADFS Server from the Proxy server.

I have added a Pass-through application in the Remote Access Management console in the Proxy server and added the backend and front end server url's as those of the internal AD FS server. When I try to access the following:

```
https://adfs.proxyserver.com/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx
```

I get a 'Webpage Not Available'. Is there any configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the ADFS Service Name - which should match your SSL certificate: i.e. `https://sts.contoso.com/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx`

Are you accessing the ADFS externally or internally when you get this error?